# php - buscar y eliminar palabras de una variable de sesion

Tags: php

//Me gustaria buscar y  eliminar ciertas palabras de una variable de sesion. //En este caso la variable contiene una consulta que se genera en otro archivo PHP. 
//Para ello deseo eliminar los AND vacios.
//La consulta es la siguinete: `$_SESSION["consulta_temporal"] = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (id='user1') AND () AND (nombre='usuario1'";`

```
<?php
session_start();
$consulta = $_SESSION["consulta_temporal"]; // aqui mando a traer la variable de sesion de otr

if (strpos($consulta, '() AND') !== false) {
$resultado1 = substr($consulta, 6);
}
else{
$resultado1 = $consulta ;
}

echo $resultado1;
?>
```

Comment: Por qué llevas una consulta entera en una variable de sesión? No tiene mucho sentido y le estás mostrando los campos de tu base de datos a cualquiera, es muy inseguro

Comment: @JulianMartinez puedes aplicar el str_replace 
 `$consulta = str_replace($_SESSION["consulta_temporal"], " ", "AND ()");`
 `str_replace ( $search , $replace , $string  ) ;`
Este remplaza contenido del string por otra. 
P.D: Deberías mandar la consulta por POST o hacerla en el mismo php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `explode`, lo conviertes en un `array` y luego vuelves a montar el `string`.

```
$array = explode("AND ()",$consulta);
$string = implode(" ", $array);
```

Dicho esto, en una variable de sesión sería más correcto pasar los valores de los campos que necesitas para la consulta y montar la query en el archivo php, no llevarla ya montada.